# Stop and restart a FreeRTOS task on another core?

Tags: c, task, scheduling, freertos

Let's say I work on a FreeRTOS application on an MCU with two cores. There are tasks running on core 1 of the format:

```c
void mytask_01( void* pvParameters ) {
  while (1) {
    ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY); // sleep and wait for notification to wake
    do_something_first_01();
    do_something_else_02();
    do_something_different_03();
    // all done, go back to sleeping
  }
}
```

So, at any given time, core 1 might be running some of these tasks - or it might be idle.

Anyways - what I want to do is: if I receive a certain interrupt on core 0, I want to stop whatever task is running; and run another initialization task, and then let the core 1 processes run as if started anew.

First problem is, I cannot tell how to find the currently running FreeRTOS task hanlde on core 1 from an interrupt on core 0: the only thing I've found in the API so far is [RTOS task (thread) utilities: xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle()](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle); however it has a signature:

```
TaskHandle_t xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle( void );  // The handle of the currently running (calling) task.
```

... but I assume this would return currently running task on "this"/"current" core - and I'd want to get the currently running task on another core.

But let's say I obtain that task handle somehow - how can I then "stop" the currently running task? Let's say, when the interrupt hits on core 0, it is the `mytask_01()` above running on core 1, and it is executing the `do_something_else_02();` function at that moment. Let's say I get the `mytask_01` task handle in this interrupt on core 0. If I just call [vTaskSuspend()](https://www.freertos.org/a00130.html):

```
void vTaskSuspend( TaskHandle_t xTaskToSuspend );
```

... I assume FreeRTOS will "freeze" `mytask_01` at the point of execution, that is somewhere in the `do_something_else_02()` function - so if I afterwards call [vTaskResume()](https://www.freertos.org/a00131.html):

```
void vTaskResume( TaskHandle_t xTaskToResume );
```

... the `mytask_01` would continue from the point in the `do_something_else_02()` function where it was suspended. But I do **NOT** want that - what I want is: once the `mytask_01` has been stopped/suspended, next time it is woken, I want it to start *from the beginning*: i.e. enter the `while(1)` loop, then end up on the `ulTaskNotifyTake()` and sleep - and then when woken by a notification signal the next time, the `mytask_01` should start with executing `do_something_first_01()`.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Why not use normal C features; break out of `while` loop to outer task loop which loops back to beginning, or just plain `goto` back at the start of task?

Comment: Thanks @user694733 - I don't how could I do that "exernally", that is, do that (e.g. break out of `while` loop) in a task running on core 1, from an ISR running on core 0?

Comment: Related: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2019/01/20/freertos-how-to-end-and-restart-the-scheduler/ "This article describes a port for ARM Cortex-M which implements vTaskEndScheduler() and the ability to call vTaskStartScheduler() again without a power-on reset" - although, I don't really want to stop and start the entire scheduler ...

Comment: I was thinking that first core would write some kind of shared data which other core would monitor. I haven't used multicore MCU with FreeRTOS and I don't know what kind of MCU architecture you have, but from your question it seems that function calls across cores is possible (?) so I assumed there is some kind of shared memory available. Perhaps you could use FreeRTOS queues for messaging somehow?

Comment: Repost on https://forums.freertos.org/t/stop-and-restart-a-freertos-task-on-another-core/18024/3 - general conclusion: no way to do this, as it is not adviseable